# DateFormat is printing new Date(0) as epoch + 1 hour

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

The following test fails:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
assertEquals("00:00:00 GMT", df.format(new Date(0)));
```

*expected "00:00:00 GMT" but was "01:00:00 GMT"*

Could someone point out where I'm being stupid please?

I've spent longer looking at this than is would have taken me to just replace everything with Joda-Time. There's a lesson there somewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that Java has a bug around the name of the Europe/London time zone abbreviation in 1970.

In the winter of 1970, the UK was still on UTC+1 - but Java believes it's still called "GMT". So what you're seeing is the *local* time at midnight UTC on January 1st 1970... it's just that we're used to GMT=UTC, which is why it's confusing.

(As a side note, it would still be worth converting to Joda Time even now. Avoid the built-in libraries like the plague :)

Joda Time prints the time zone abbreviation as "BST". This seems equally bizarre given that it clearly *wasn't* summer time... but it's possible that the "S" here standards for Standard, as that was during the period of the "British Standard Time experiment". See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) for details.

(Note that UTC itself didn't even exist at the Unix epoch - it was introduced in 1972. I'm assuming a proleptic UTC for the sake of this answer :)

Comment: Ah. I just read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time#Periods_of_deviation and it mentions that Britain was experimenting with a temporary time-zone change. Thanks Jon.

Comment: There are quite a few years during the wars and 1970-1985 where the daylight saving times were introduced or changed through out Europe. (during WW2, the offset were 2 hours in UK. I suppose it was still called GMT )  I don't thin it's an error in the tables in Java, but rather a problematic corner case - the model isn't complex enough. "CET" for instance,  was introduce gradually in central Europe, so for a specific country, it's incorrect for at least a few years in seventies. Calendars (the concept, not the class) and time is annoyingly complicated, and it easy to get confused.

Comment: BTW, You would think UTC is initials for something when its a compromise of the English and French initial-isms. i.e. its not quite either of them.

Comment: Before the Gregorian calendar the year changed on March the 25th (nine months before Dec 25th ;) When the USA gained independence it adopted the calendar retrospectively. George Washington's birthday was February 11, 1731 when he was born but it changed to February 22, 1732 during his lifetime. Greece adopted the Gregorian calendar in 1924, making the time difference between Italy and Greece 13 days in 1923.

Answer (score 0):

[new Date(0)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29) returns Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

So the value will be Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970

"05:30:00" Depens on your location

Comment: The OP is confused because of the GMT being output along with 01:00:00. Most Britons don't realise that on the date of the Unix epoch, Britain was on UTC+1. Not that UTC existed at the time...

Comment: The Epoch is stated in GMT, and I specifically formatted the output to include the timezone, which is GMT.

Comment: Yes, but in 1969-1971 the timezone in UK wasn't GMT but rather British Standard Time (UTC+1) all year around. This is reflected in the offsets for the timezone called "GMT" but it's name is not changed in java. I think it is actually handled as if wintertime never happes those years. Anyway,  The encouraged timezone identifier is "Europe/London" - representing the whole administrative region, rather than a specific timezone, as a specific place may have (had) several timezones.